# How to conditional Format based off of the day of the week?

Tags: google-sheets

I am having trouble figuring out how to conditional format based on the day of the week. Is there a formula that is known to work?

[image: See here for example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"dddd")="Monday"
```

should work for what you're doing.